# How can I set custom CSS on clusters in Leaflet.markercluster

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

[leaflet clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0lNg.png)I want to set different styles on each cluster based on the clusters child count in the layer

that means for example
if the cluster had values like 5, 12, 109, 1900, 21900 then the circle sizes should be increased by 10px of the next size, something like as shown in the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqPbg.png),

```
const markers = new window.L.MarkerClusterGroup({
            iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
                var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
                console.log({childCount, cluster,tempClusterCount, pr:cluster, c:cluster.getAllChildMarkers()})
                var c = ' marker-cluster-';
                if (childCount < 10) {
                  c += 'small';
                } 
                else if (childCount < 100) {
                  c += 'medium';
                } 
                else {
                  c += 'large';
                }
               
                return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', 
                 className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
                },
                
        });
```

with the above code, we can add the custom class based on the custom condition, but I want to check all the other clusters on the layer, do we have any method to get parent clusters details?

do we have any method to get parent cluster details from a cluster?

something like :

```
const markers = new window.L.MarkerClusterGroup({             iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {                 var childCount = cluster.parent.getChildCount(); } })
```

Comment: What does "_parent cluster_" mean to you? Can you provide a specific example case of how you would like your map to behave?

Comment: that means, for example, I have 500 data points, and when I click on the first cluster point(500) then I can see the next children from this may be with 127, 122, 141, 110, and when I click on any of the data points then I can see the next points 20, 27, 28, 51 and 1 at this zoom level so now I want to see/ get either parent clusters either I want to get all the parallel clusters at this zoom level, because if I get all the parallel cluster  then I can display the cluster size based on the count